# Can't turn on backlight for Cooler Master Devastator II Keyboard on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, keyboard-backlight

I have followed this link https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/cm-storm-keyboard-and-mouse-solved/9816 .

I used this command 
`sudo xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'`

but it's showing me following msg 
`xmodmap:  unable to open display 'desktop:0'`.

when I use `xset led 3`. it's not turning on backlit.

Can anyone tell me what's going on ?

Answer (score 2):

I created a script "keyboardLedOn.sh" with:

```
#! /bin/sh
xset -led 2 led on
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-enable true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-enable false
```

Then in the end of my .profile file (~/.profile) put:

```
/path/to/script/keyboardLedOn.sh
```

I hope someone can help to improve, I know it's not a good answer, but it works

Comment: it's not working for me

Answer (score 1):

I was breaking my head trying to solve this one, this is what I did:

```
sudo su
echo 3 > /sys/class/leds/input5::scrolllock/brightness
```

I created an script that toggles the on and off as a sudoer:

```
#!/bin/sh

TOGGLE=$HOME/.toggle

if [ ! -e $TOGGLE ]; then
    touch $TOGGLE
    echo 3 > /sys/class/leds/input5::scrolllock/brightness
else
    rm $TOGGLE
    echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/input5::scrolllock/brightness
fi
```

Still no luck trying to bind it to the scroll lock key...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still looking for an answer but at lest in ubuntu 20.04 only put on terminal

```
xset led 3
```

thats it

That's what it work for me, sorry if for you don't

Comment: and didn't need sudo ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check for empty map:
(Most likely map3)

```
xmodmap -pm
```

In terminal type:

```
xmodmap -e "add mod3 = Scroll_Lock"
```